# React + PropTypes and ESlint error: How to validate props of a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, react-proptypes

I have this `Route` [from `react-router`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/820#issuecomment-313794272):

```
<Route
    path="/:url*"
    exact
    strict
    render={props => <Redirect to={`${props.location.pathname}/`} />}
/>
```

It simply adds a trailing slash to routes that haven't one.

But ESLint signals an error on `props.location.pathname` as both `props.location` and `props.location.pathname` are not validate with `PropTypes`.

How can I validate them? Is there a way?

NOTE: I don't want to ignore the rule: I want to fix it explicitly validating the props!

Comment: you will need to define that component outside of the prop, set the propTypes, and then just reference that component in the render prop

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so following the @Tiago Coelho's comment to my question, here is the solution:

```
// RedirectToTrailingSlash.jsx
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const RedirectToTrailingSlash = props => (
  <Redirect to={`${props.location.pathname}/`} />
);

RedirectToTrailingSlash
  .propTypes = { location: PropTypes.shape({ pathname: PropTypes.string.isRequired }).isRequired };

export default RedirectToTrailingSlash;
```

And this is the rewrote `Route`:

```
// YourComponent.jsx
...
<Route
    path="/:url*"
    exact
    strict
    component={RedirectToTrailingSlash}
/>
...
```